# Recognize Upper Right Icons (status bar)

Tags: android

I'm actually trying to implement a feature for my app to recognize, on the status bar, the icons like wifi, airplane mode, nfc, etc... and then compare it to what was expected to appear.

Until now, I've only seen getActiveNotifications() -- On API 18 or 23 -- but those methods don't let me access the right corner notifications.

Does anyone know if there exists something in android to get access to those notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API which gives you information about "icons". But right icons are about system state. So you can get some information about network state(wifi, cell), battery level, time, bluetooth state and others.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll just give it up then, I've already got something to do this